# PowerShell: Is there a way to add time/date stamps to the debug output?

Tags: powershell, logging

I've been using set-psdebug to send debug output to the console. I'd like to improve that by adding a time/date stamp since the output is captured and this would help troubleshoot issues after the fact. Anyone doing this or know how to do this?

This scripts all use:

```
set-psdebug -trace 1
```

this causes the output to look like this:

```
Debug:   14+  >>>> $ToFolder = "${UnixUserid}@${UnixServer}:${UnixFile}"
```

the goal is to add the time/date stamp to the left hand side of the Debug

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but is this not an option: `Write-Debug "$(Get-Date) This is some debug text"`

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: What about using a custom function that includes `Set-PSDebug` and `Write-Debug`?

Comment: Honestly I'm really not sure how that would work but I'm certainly open to trying it

Answer (score 2):

I think the built-in cmdlet `Set-TraceSource` is the most frictionless way to accomplish what you're wanting. You'll want to play around with the values available for -Option. I did try instantiating my own TraceListeners with higher TraceLevels but couldn't figure out how to get them bound to the running powershell console.

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
Set-TraceSource -Name "ParameterBinding" -Option ExecutionFlow -PSHost -ListenerOption "DateTime"
foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i }
```

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-tracesource?view=powershell-6

Comment: This great I can't wait to try this!

Comment: I do not know how this can be useful. The output is polluted with great amount of useless information. It is impossible to actually get the timings of the commands one cares about. Is there a better way?